# How to detect and display Javascript error from AJAX call in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Rails app that receives form data and renders some Javascript. Here is an example of such a response:

[image: response]

The Rails app generates the Javascript without error and serves it with the correct content-type and a status code of 200. So on this tab in the DevTools there is no apparent error.

However, there is an error *in the Javascript itself*, namely an undefined function:

[image: console log]

As you can see, I have "Log XMLHttpRequests" turned on in my DevTool settings. Javascript errors triggered from page events appear in the Console as expected, but Javascript errors from AJAX calls don't. The only way I can discover that there was an error in the returned Javascript is to copy/paste the code from the response into the Console.

This seems like a pretty critical feature that just doesn't exist. Am I missing something or is this simply not possible with Chrome DevTools? If so, is there a workaround to this problem that would fit into my workflow?

Comment: is the javascript in the response actually being run after the response comes back?

Comment: Yes, up until the point where the error occurs.

Comment: This is quite strange behaviour...if i have some javascript which is run from the response of an ajax call i can see it error in my console.  Try putting some `console.log("...");` lines in your javascript code to see if it is actually running and if it can communicate with the console in this way.

Comment: If I put `console.log('before'); bad_function(); console.log('after')` in the Javascript, I only get "before" logged in the console and no error.

Comment: And how exactly are you executing code that you get via AJAX? eval? Injecting `<script>` into the DOM?

Comment: That's getting interpreted and evaluated by jquery_ujs since it's a Rails project.